# Почему запрещено наследование от значимых типов?

Tags: c#, наследование, struct, c#-faq

Почему запрещено наследование от значимых типов, например `struct`? То что `struct` `sealed` - это понятно:) Но почему её сделали `sealed`?

Comment: @andreycha, всё-таки вопрос был именно о структурах, да и лидирующий и единственный в данный момент ответ только о них, а не о всех значимых типах.

Comment: @4per а никакой разницы нет.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Проблема вот в чём. Допустим, разрешено было бы наследоваться от структур.

Рассмотрим такой код:

```
class C1
{
    int x;
}

class C2 : C1
{
    int y;
    public override string ToString() { return y.ToString(); }
}
```

Вы можете написать так: `C1 c = new C2();` и вызвать `c.ToString();`. Поскольку `c` является лишь ссылкой на данные, проблем с вызовом не возникает. Это стандартная фича, базовое полиморфное поведение ссылочных типов.

Представьте себе теперь аналогичную ситуацию:

```
struct S1
{
    int x;
}

struct S2 : S1
{
    int y;
    public override string ToString() { return y.ToString(); }
}

S1 s = new S2();
```

Что будет в `s`? Из соображений эффективности структуры хранятся в памяти *как есть*, то есть, просто набор полей, а не ссылка на них. Это значит, что под `s` отводится столько байт, сколько занимает `S1`, и для поля `y` там просто нет места! Что в этом случае должен вернуть вызов `s.ToString()`?

Аналогичная проблема возникает при передаче параметров производного типа в функцию, требующую аргумент базового типа.

Эта проблема называется *slicing*, и она актуальна для дизайна многих языков программирования. Например, она присутствует в C++. Решение в C# — отказаться от наследования структур: допустить неработающий полиморфизм при наследовании — плохая идея. При таком решении slicing в C# исключён.

Другие языки решают проблему по-другому. Например, в C++ настоящим типом объекта `s` будет просто `S1`, а не `S2`, и `y` просто потеряется. Создатели языка C# считают такое поведение неинтуитивным, ведущим к проблемам и ошибкам, поэтому они пошли по другому пути. Если вам нужно наследование, в C# нужно воспользоваться классами, или перейти к композиции.

---

Проблему *можно* было бы решить, если бы структуры хранились точно так же, как и классы: не значение, а ссылка на него. При этом операции наподобие присвоения должны были бы для сохранения семантики копировать не ссылку, а *значение* всё равно. Но такой подход, хоть и разрешил бы наследование структур, сильно ухудшил бы их *эффективность*: каждая операция со структурой стала бы медленнее из-за лишнего косвенного доступа, плюс аллокация структур в общем случае была бы вытеснена из стека в кучу.

Архитекторы языка разменяли полиморфизм структур на их эффективность.

Comment: Не понял, в C# есть slicing? Создатель языка C++, к слову, считает точно так же :)

Comment: @ixSci: Он был бы, если бы разрешили наследование структур.

Comment: Тогда Вам стоит перефразировать предложение, я считаю. Т.к. сейчас оно построена так, как-будто slicing в C# есть.

Comment: @ixSci *"Эта проблема называется slicing, и она присутствует"* -- ОНА, т.е. проблема.

Comment: @andreycha, как эта проблема может присутствовать в языке, в котором этой возможности нет? «Нет человека — нет проблемы»

Comment: Окей, переформулировал. Надеюсь, так текст получится более однозначным.

Comment: *если бы структуры хранились точно так же, как и классы*, они не были бы структурами!

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Ну вы слишком уж формалист. «Если бы при проектировании языка было решено хранить структуры так, ...» — устраивает? То есть, да, если бы словом «структура» (а точнее, «значимый тип») называлось нечто другое.

Comment: @VladD чем бы в таком случае значимые типы отличались от ссылочных?

Comment: @VladD в данный момент способ хранения - ключевой; все остальные особенности являются прямыми следствиями

Comment: @PavelMayorov: Тем же, чем и сейчас: семантикой равенства и копирования/присваивания.

Comment: Сошлюсь на [статью Эрика](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2009/04/27/the-stack-is-an-implementation-detail-part-one/).

Comment: То есть скорее не равенства, а идентичности: два одинаковых по содержанию экземпляра value type неотличимы, а экземпляр reference type обладает собственной идентичностью.